# I am working on React where i want to fill the red color on Ionicon Icon when user Click on this icon using useState Hook

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic-framework

When I am try to do. It Change Background color of Icon

//This is my Code

```
    export default function Preview() {
        const [color, setColors] = React.useState("");
        const handleClickButton = () => {
            setColors(
                "red"
            
            )
          };

       return(

     <div>
        <a className="icons mr-3" onClick={()=> handleClickButton()} ><ion-icon name="heart-outline" 
        style= {{backgroundColor:color}}></ion-icon></a>
     </div>

)
}
```

When I Click its show me like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2YUi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's changing the icon to red as you expect? Then again, you haven't fully explained what your goal is here.

EDIT: try to target heart color by using color instead of background-color:

```
 <div>
    <a className="icons mr-3" onClick={()=> handleClickButton()} ><ion-icon name="heart-outline" 
    style= {{color:color}}></ion-icon></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Actually I want to fill the red color inside the heart icon when your click on this icon.

Comment: Kindly check this https://codepen.io/bojandevic/pen/mxKZqK link which may help you to understand more clearly.

Comment: To add, the snippet you provided is using font-awesome heart icon. - If you want to switch over to font-awesome it will work like your snippet.

Comment: Good to hear, if this helped, click checkmark to mark my answer correct, or upvote so it will help others. - If you found another solution it's up to you to provide it.